# Modulus of complex root

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

If $z$ is a root of the equation $$11z^{10}+10iz^9+10iz-11=0$$ Find value of $|z|$

I assumed the root as $z=re^{it}$ We get:

$$11r^{10}\cos(10t)-10r^9\sin(9t)-10r\sin (t)-11=0 \tag{1}$$ and
$$11r^9\sin(10t)+10r^8\cos(9t)+10\cos(t)=0 \tag{2}$$

Any way from here?

Comment: I think this is a past Putnam problem.

Comment: Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1907706/11619), and in [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h106680p602504).

Comment: Feel free to us another incarnation as the dupe target. [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%2411z%5E%7B10%7D%2B10iz%5E9%2B10iz-11%3D0%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to show by Rouche that all critical points are in the closed unit disc - this is immediate since $P'(z)=110z^9+90iz^8+10i$ and $110>90+10$ so $|P'(z)-110z^9|<|110z^9|$ on the unit circle etc

But now $P$ is self inversive since if $z$ is a root, $\frac{1}{\bar z}$ is a root and then it is an easy exercise to show that a self inversive $P$ must have all the roots on the unit circle when all its critical points are inside the closed unit disc so $|z|=1$

($\Re{\frac{zf'}{f}}>0, 1<|z|<1+\epsilon$ and the argument principle)

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure, but if you try to resolve $11\left(z^{10}-1\right)+10i\left(z^9+1\right)=0$ maybe it´s gonna be more easy.